# iOS: Can I intercept swipes on top of a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swipe

I want the user to be able to swipe left, right, upward and downward on a UIWebview, but I don't want the HTML/Javascript to process those swipes-- I want to do that myself.

Is that possible: To intercept just the swipes? I want the taps still to go through to the UIWebview.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Sure thing.
Just attach UIGestureRecognizer subclass to that view and hold on for calls...

```
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer* leftSwipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(someAction)];
    leftSwipeRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    leftSwipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    leftSwipeRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
    [self.webView addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipeRecognizer];
```

there is some sample for left swipe gesture. You can set more with very similar approach...
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) onto the UIWebview with

```
addGestureRecognizer:
```

it will allow you to get those events.  I believe the default is to only allow one recognizer at a time, but I'm not sure if that applies to individual gesture types or across all gesture types, so this may only be the first step in solving your problem.